# Jquery if all checkboxes selected show() ... else hide() 

Tags: jquery

I have 3 checkboxes and 2 divs. I want to be able to show one div when all 3 checkboxes have been ticked and show the other div when any other combination of checkboxes are ticked (ie not all 3).
It would be very much appreciated if anybody could help me out with some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="3" type="checkbox" />

<div id="checked1">Title</div>

<div id="checked2" style="display:none;"><span style="color:green;">Title</span></div>


$(document).ready(function() {

$(('input#1')&&('input#2')&&('input#3')).change(
    function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $("#checked2").show();
             $("#checked1").hide();

        } else {
              $("#checked1").show();
             $("#checked2").hide();
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this code work? Does it do what you want it to?

Comment: @Christian Mann - If someone posts a question, it means they need an answer, why would he post what he has if it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $cBoxes = $('#1,#2,#3');

$cBoxes.change(function(){
  // check if all are checked based on if the number of checkboxes total
  // is equal to the number of checkboxes checked
  if ($cBoxes.length == $cBoxes.filter(':checked').length){
    $('#checked2').show();
    $('#checked1').hide();
  }else{
    $('#checked2').hide();
    $('#checked1').show();
  }
});
```

Something like that?

Comment: I would use `input[type="checkbox"]` as selector but apart from that: Exactly what I was thinking :) +1

Comment: @FelixKling: I debated that, but didn't know if there was an explicit list of checkboxes, or if others were possibly on the page that should remain exempt. ;-)

Comment: @bradchristie: wow that was a fast response, its is working now cheers although i used ShankarSangoli response which was very similar.

Comment: @bradchristie: i presume if i wanted to do this again for another 3 checkboxes on the same page it would work.

Comment: @bradchristie: i presume if i wanted to do this again for another 3 checkboxes on the same page it would work. i could just create a diff var secondsetchkBoxes = $('#chk4,#chk5,#chk6');

Comment: @Matthew: The best would be to give the parent element an ID: `$('#someId input')`

Comment: @felix-kling: The code worked great when using jsfiddle.com but now i have put it into my script it ceases to work? What version of jquery do i need? Im using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js. I am also using a checkbox js script to change to sliding images and also cluetip script, would these conflict?

Comment: @Matthew: The checkbox-to-image script may be doing it, the checkbox may not be firing a change event (or the control is storing the information elsewhere). What's the exact plugin you're using?

Comment: @Brad Christie: thanks for the reply, the checkbox to image script is from this URL: http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Comment: @Matthew: I tried it and it [doesn't appear](http://jsfiddle.net/aKxgg/) to interfere with any of the events, so everything should work fine. Can you post either a pastbin or a jsFiddle with the entire code you have? I'm curious what may be conflicting.

Comment: @Brad Christie: only prob is its a bit messy and quite large. I have the same script working but only one checkbox in the var, var $cBoxes = $('#ctl'); it just doesn't seem to work for the multiple checkboxes. I have also found another issue, with this being a form the user fills in, they can save it and come back to it at anytime. Therefor the change event dosnt always get invoked as they could have already saved that option so the only event would be the database checking the field with php. Hope that made sense, Regards

Comment: @Brad Christie: I have got the multiple checkboxes working now. So just need to figure out how to do it if 3 are checked rather than on change, due to the fact im getting checked values from a database.

Comment: @Matthew: Refactor the code in to a separate function, and bind it to the change event, but also fire it on page load. Allow the logic to run in both places.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Managed to do the seperate function and its working now, thanks. I used $cBoxes.ready(function(){

Comment: @Brad Christie: How do i apply both of these functions if i want to disable the checkboxes and use a link instead for the user to click?<input type="checkbox" id="co1" name="co1" <?php if($mychecklist->co1==1) echo 'checked="checked"' ?>/>
<a target="_blank" onClick="document.checklist.co1.value=1;" href="">Link</a>

Comment: @Matthew: I'm not sure I understand. You want a link to fire the function instead of on a change event?

Comment: @Brad Christie: the checkbox will be the image i previosly talked about but will be disabled so the user cant click it but can still see it. Next to it will be a link that when clicked the checkbox will change. the onClick="document.checklist.co1.value=1;" does that fine. but this does not seem to invoke the jquery change event.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Any ideas on the clicking of the link to invoke the jquery change for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have ids starting or just the number. Try this

```
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="chk2" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="chk3" type="checkbox" />





var chkBoxes = $('#chk1,#chk2,#chk3');

      chkBoxes .change(function(){

      if (chkBoxes.filter(':checked').length == chkBoxes.length){
        $('#checked2').show();
        $('#checked1').hide();
      }else{
        $('#checked2').hide();
        $('#checked1').show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    var checked = true; // assume checked

    $(':input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            checked = false; // set false if any are unchecked, exit loop
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (checked) {
        $('#checked2').show();
        $('#checked1').hide();
    } else {
        $('#checked1').show();
        $('#checked2').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `checkbox` isn't a valid selector. Perhaps you were looking for `[type="checkbox"]`?